# Twitter Bootstrap: Carousel: Vertically Center Image in Definded height Viewport

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am attempting to find a way to verticially center an image inside of my viewport for the carousel. Currently the images are working fine and it is resizing the image to the size of the viewport on the width. But I want to use the center of the image and crop the top and bottom of the photo.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="carousel slide hero">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="active item">
            <img src="img/hero/1.jpg" />
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="img/hero/2.jpg" />
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="img/hero/3.jpg" />
       </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control left" href=".hero" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href=".hero" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div><!-- hero -->
```

and the small bit of css:

```
.carousel-inner {
    height: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I want it so that if they upload any size photo it can be considered usable.

Comment: Please pick a valid answer if any of them helped you out

Answer (score 20):

I have solved this problem by specifying the .item height and making the image in it absolutely positioned:

```
.item {
height: 300px;
}

.item img {
max-height: 100%;  
max-width: 100%; 
position: absolute;  
top: 0;  
bottom: 0;  
left: 0;  
right: 0;  
margin: auto;
}
```

This will make a carousel 300px height with images centered vertically and horizontally.

Comment: I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509980/vertically-align-image-inside-a-bootstrap-carousel?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/css-vertical-align-middle-not-working), but none of them worked. But this solution works perfectly, thank you sir!

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know the height of images, you can use next styles

```
#product-detail .carousel-inner{
    height: 500px;
}

#product-detail .carousel-inner>.active{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#product-detail .carousel-inner>.next,
#product-detail .carousel-inner>.prev{
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

here, `#product-detail` is used as wrapper to override bootstrap styles.
also, don't forget to wendorize `transform`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem for me.  Also, in order to make sure it wouldn't continue to scale past the point where it would be so small that white margins would come in, I added a min-width:'768px' to the wrapper.  Hope this helps other people too

Comment: This worked perfectly! I don't understand the phrase "don't forget to wendorize transform" though oO

Comment: It works for images, but captions get hidden below the carousel viewport. How to pull them up into position?

Comment: @xtian set vendor-prefixes I believe e.g. http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/

Comment: @grigson is it expected that when images cycle, they will scroll diagonally to the bottom-left, then move upwards?

Comment: This trick doesn't work anymore on Bootstrap v3.3.2; any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following, this positions the image in the center of the carousel viewport and sets
the height to 320px

```
.carousel-inner>.item>img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 320px;
}
```

Hoped this helped you out

Comment: Lol he said vertically align

Comment: This only aligns the image horizontally

Answer (score 1):

This Might be help you

Try Out this Plugin

https://github.com/tutorialdrive/Bootstrap-Vertical-Thumbnail-Carousel

And take a look over here.

[Twitter Bootstrap Vertical Thumbnail Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416892/how-to-create-carousel-in-bootstrap-with-vertical-thumbnail/18416893#18416893)

Answer (score 0):

I added just a little bit to YorickH answer

```
.carousel-inner>.item>img {
margin: 0 auto;
height: 600px;
width: 100%;
}
```

This makes sure tje images stretch to the end of the screen (or your container), and increases the height a little so the images don't look so stretched and squished.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to center images in carousel either

grigson's answer worked great on firefox, but did not work on Chrome. So after a lot of struggling I came up with this solution:

Put the images as a background of *div.item*, because that way you can easily position them without disturbing the layout:

```
.carousel-inner .item {
    width: 100%; /* Your width */
    height: 500px; /* Your height */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover; /* This also makes sure it fills the whole div */
}

/* add the images to divs */
div.item:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-image: url("../img/carousel-photos/1.jpg");
}

div.item:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-image: url("../img/carousel-photos/2.jpg");
}

div.item:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-image: url("../img/carousel-photos/3.jpg");
}

div.item:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-image: url("../img/carousel-photos/4.jpg");
}
```

It may not be the best way to do it, but it works really well for me.