# HTML Vertical-align failed?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form that consists of 2 textboxs. I'm just trying to make the form appearing in the middle of the page. There are no any extra elements in the page. By using `align="center"` the elements does move to the center but it's not the case for `vertical-align:middle`?

```
<html>
<body style="vertical-align: middle;">

<form>
<div align="center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
<h1>blabla</h1>
<label>
<span>Username: </span><input id="userName" type="text" name="userName" />
</label><br/>

<label>
<span>Password: &nbsp;</span><input id="passWord" type="password" name="passWord" />
</label><br/>
<input type="button" value="Login" />
</label>

</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/css-vertical-align-middle-not-working) and [this site](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/) for the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following CSS, it centers the content both vertically and horizontally.

You need to set the `html`/`body` to `height:100%`, then set the body, or the parent to `display:table`. After that, set the child to `display:table-cell`, and `vertical-align:middle`. That will take care of the vertical alignment. In order to center horizontally, use `margin:0px auto;`, and set a width on the form.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sjk6m/)

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
body {
    display:table;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
form {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:240px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Full screen result here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjk6m/embedded/result/

Comment: Note that the table and table-cell display properties don't work in IE<8.

Comment: @j08691 What's IE8 ;) ?

Comment: It's Redmondian for steaming pile of shiznit.