# I'm using a section tag instead of a div and I need to move it to the very center of the screen

Tags: html, css

Here's my form and section code:

```
<section class="loginform tmr">
    <form name="login" action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <ul>
            <li><label for="usermail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required>  
            </li>
            <li><label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required> 
            </li>
            <li><input type="submit" value="Login"></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</section>
```

Perhaps I am just doing it wrong but I have tried `margin: 0 auto` and also `display: inline-block`.

I do not want to use `position: relative` because I fear it will be all over the place on different monitors.

Any help for the most sound and efficient way to accomplish this rather simple task would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid setting a width on the element by using this approach [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/MP6Xd/)

This works with dynamic content of varying widths. The trick is to change the elements to `inline-block` and set `text-align:center` on the parent for centering.

```
body { text-align:center; }
section, form {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Alternatively, set a width on the `section` element, and use `margin:0 auto`. By default a `section` is a block level element which functions as though it has a width of 100%. Therefore you would need a width in order to center it. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/MP6Xd/1/)

Comment: That works great but it's centered at the top of the screen I need it to drop down to the middle as well, in the center of the top and bottom as well as left to right.

Comment: I think he is saying he wants it vertically and horizontally centered.

Comment: If you want vertical centering as @JoshMein suggests, take a look at this old answer of mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440672/html-vertical-align-failed/19440725#19440725 ... alternatively you can also look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically/19461564#19461564

Comment: Yes @JoshMein, dead center in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a width set on your section in order for `margin:0 auto` to work.

CSS:

```
.loginform
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BBrb9/1/)