# Why is this css vertical-align not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, styling

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VY7rc/4/) is my code.

I have added the `vertical-align` property for the `spans` in the `div` with `ed_button` class but the `third,` `fourth` and the `fifth boxes` are displaying the spans at top positions not in the middle.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VY7rc/6/ is this you want?

Comment: This might help you for sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/css-vertical-align-middle-not-working

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian: I wanted all my divs of same width.

Comment: @ThankYouSRT check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VY7rc/30/)

Comment: @ThankYouSRT i have posted an answer can you please check that and let me know is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the outer-div `display: table`. And `float: left` will fulfill your purpose of horizontal alignment.

```
.ed_button{
    display: table;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

and the inner-div should have `display: table-cell`

```
.ed_button span{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Check out the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/usmanz/VY7rc/42/)** here.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` property will work for `table` or `table-cell`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/VY7rc/7/)

Comment: the entire format has been chagned

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian Maybe but I have given OP the answer why vertical-align didn't worked.  I was not sure about the format

Comment: but he needs the output, stating reason can be done by noob too, insteasd why dont you help him to get his answer

Answer (score 0):

since you have fixed dimension, i would suggest to remove `span` from multi-line and instead use `line-height` = `div` height trick for the purpose of single-line text

```
.ed_button span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: auto;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VY7rc/36/)

Answer (score 0):

I have added this to the CSS Part

```
.ed_button {     
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-right: 5px #FFFFFF solid;
}
```

### <kbd>[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VY7rc/40/)</kbd>

Comment: This is ok if the background color is white, what if have a background image?

Answer (score 0):

```
.ed_button{
    background-color: #F9A11A;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
        }
```

Use this css style for your code it 'll work fine

Answer (score -1):

None of your text are alligned in middle. It is just beacause there is more text in the 1st and 2nd box that it seems to be in middle.

You can also try padding-top, margin-top or Position properties of css.