# Vertical-Align a Block Element

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have an image and text next to each other in a div. I'm trying to align the text vertically aligned in the middle, but it stays on top. Please help!

http://jsfiddle.net/9KDva/

HTML:

```
<div class="title-block">
  <div class="img-holder"><img width="101" height="104" src="http://www.test.com/test.jpeg" /></div>
  <div class="title">Get Your Nose Out of Your IPhone</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title-block {
width:272px;
height: 110px;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.img-holder {
float: left;
margin: 0 6px 0 0;
position: relative;
}

.img-holder img {
display: block;
}

.title {
display:block;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 8px 0 9px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS vertical-align: middle not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/css-vertical-align-middle-not-working)

Comment: this link will help understand vertical aligment http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `table` and `table-cell`: And move your `class='title'` inside `img-holder`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KDva/2/)

With padding left away from `image` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KDva/3/)

```
.title-block {
    width:272px;
    height: 110px;    
}

.img-holder {    
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}

img, .title{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 8px 0 9px;  
}
```

Comment: Since the question is how to align a block, changing display to table-cell, does not help anyone trying to vertically align an element with display block. Might as well use flex alignment if your willing to change display.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your div to span for `vertical-align: middle` to work.

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9KDva/4/

CSS:

```
.vam {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.vam {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="title-block">
   <span class="img-holder vam">
<img width="101" height="104" src="http://www.girlsguidetomanners.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/url-16-101x104.jpeg" class="attachment-homepoststhumbnail wp-post-image" alt="url-16" /></span>
    <span class="title vam">Get Your Nose Out of Your IPhone</span>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vertical-align: middle won't work on a div.

Something like this might work:

```
<table class="title-block" style="background-image:url('http://www.girlsguidetomanners.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/url-16-101x104.jpeg); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
  <tr>
     <td class="title" style="vertical-align: middle;">
         Get Your Nose Out of Your IPhone
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables should *only* be used for tabular content, not for layout!