# How to use inline css styling (style="vertical-alignment:middle;") in html5 <img> or <iframe> tags

Tags: css, image, iframe

**Note all <> tags have been removed to allow code to display
**
i have been playing around with this for hours and am not really getting it to work without using a workaround at the design end of things (ie Corel draw)

*Before i go any further,

*First, website URL is AdventistAviation.com.au*

*Second, can i just say...i know this can be done with style sheets...however, in this case...i am not doing it that way!!! (so please dont bother pestering me with that option unless there is absolutely no way the method below can work)*

*Third, a workaround to my problem below, is to create the image already centered in its own background (the same size as the logo next to it) then import it (this is a bad idea because if in the future someone changes the main header background to a different color other than white...its gonna look awful!)*

1. First i add the image (this works no problem)

However because the Logo on the left in the avada theme is approx 250×250 square, Tagline text is no longer centered in the header (as you can imagine comparing above with logo below)

I am using the themeforest AVADA Theme. In theme options>Banner Code For Header #4…

I would like to add the following inline css styling in an iframe for example, to vertically centre the Tagline (ie bring it down level with the middle of the logo)

style="vertical-align: middle;"

```
<iframe src="http://image_URL.png" style=”vertical:align: middle;” width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

This doesnt seem to do anything different to the method in 1.

```
<div style="vertical-align: middle;"><iframe src="http://image_URL.png" width="200" height="200"></iframe></div>
```

I was hoping that if i place the iframe inside a  tag containing the styling i might achieve my goal...alas it still doesnt work.

I have got to the point where my head is so full of nonworking methods i cant progress further.

Can someone help with this one?

p.s i have tried to find some inline css styling tutorials (specifically about vertical alignment styling) for the  tag in html 5 without any luck.

damn w3c for depreciating the html vertical alignment method in html5!

Comment: THis will seem like a weird comment but take out spaces between the property and the property value. EX| `<div style="vertical-align: middle;" iframe src="http://image_URL.png" width="200" height="200" /iframe /div>` There shouldnt be a space between `vertical-align:` and `middle;`

Comment: Sorry...had a hard time reading the code. Have you tried styling the iframe and/or img with margin:auto  for alignment?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please reference where it says `vertical-align` is deprecated? I wasn't aware that was the case, unless you mean the `valign` attribute. Also, I don't see why using inline styling should work any different than from a stylesheet. You can just look for regular CSS solutions instead of narrowing your search to inline specifically. It may also help others help you if you included images in your question, so that we can better understand the issue you're having. It is difficult to imagine since you're using dimensions and distances in your example.

Comment: Padding in your div (assuming 250 x 250) might also help: e.g., padding:25px;

Comment: @Brendan That *does* seem like a weird question to me because 1) There *is* a space between the property and value 2) It doesn't make a difference. `vertical-align:middle` is equivalent to `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: Hi guys, this is bloody driving up the f*&$#en wall! not only can i not get it too work...i cant get the damn code inserted into this bloody post so you can read it!!! argh!!!!!

Comment: @adam Use ``` (except only one) for inline code, and add 4 spaces to the beginning of lines for code blocks. In the text box where you write the question, there is a button on top that looks like `{ }` and says "Code Sample" when you hover over it. Highlight your code, click that, and it will appear as code.

Comment: thanks i have been trying that but was doing it the wrong way.

Comment: ok so about the inline code i am trying to make work for header tag line...does the syle="vertical-align:middle;" only work for text between the >"text here"< end and start of tags in iframe?

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO. True genious mexican style!!!! ahahahahaha thank you so much!!!!

Comment: i Think this question "<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/css-vertical-align-middle-not-working>" might help you.

Comment: @adam: The image is in the right place now, but you still have two div's with id="header-banner".  You can (and should) remove the outer div that doesn't contain the inline styling and your code will still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ adam:

A simple solution is to change this code:

```
<div id="header-banner">
    <div style="vertical-align: middle;" height="170" width="500">
        <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/...etc..." width="400" height="200">
    </div>
</div>
```

To just this:

```
<div id="header-banner" style="margin-top: 70px;">        
        <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/...." width="400" height="200">
</div>
```

Comment: This is the option i went with trevour....it was such a simple solution and this is nothing short of brilliant. much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There's no good reason to use inline styles for this, but anyhow, I've edited a chunk of your HTML with inline styles that will get what I think you want:

```
<div class="avada-row" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; display: table; width: 100%">
    <div class="logo" style="display: table-cell;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:0px; vertical-align: middle;">
        <a href="http://adventistaviation.com.au">
            <img src="http://adventistaviation.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/AAA-QLD-LogoType5_outlinedSQC1-e1398740621697.jpg" alt="Adventist Aviation Association" class="normal_logo">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="header-banner" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; float: none; text-align: right;">
        <div style="/* vertical-align: middle; */" height="170" width="500">
            <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B7IkcUtUKfX8SkpLS1NuTlR4cDA/AAA_Tagline.png" width="400" height="200">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: genius, i cant thank you enough ralph. to think i have spent almost a whole day trying to figure this out!!!!