# Abolsute Vertically center does not work in FireFox

Tags: css, image, firefox, positioning

I have the following code in my CSS

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 113px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.box img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 202px;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">image goes here</div>
```

For some reason this works perfectly for Chrome, Safari and IE.... but in Firefox the image does not center in its "BOX" container.

Does firefox not support this method?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hy92kgh0/1/)

Comment: what do you mean by "center"?! center vertically or horizontally?! In IE,FF and Chrome its looks like the same for me.

Comment: Sorry.Vertically center. Have a look at my Fiddle in Firefox and then Chrome. You will see what I mean.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/css-vertical-align-middle-not-working/23207658#23207658

Comment: @user3298192, It exactly the same. can you provide a picture of difference ?!

Comment: Kornieff it worked. Thanks. Have a look at the updated version. http://jsfiddle.net/WebbySmart/hy92kgh0/4/