# Vertical align middle footer

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to  position vertical footer. I have text and logo in it. Logo is aligned right. It has height 38 and footer must be with height of 80px. But I can't align them vertical both text and logo.

```css
#footer { height: 80px; }
#footer .text{margin: 0 auto; width: 1024px; padding-top: 35px;vertical-align:middle;}
#footer .text #logo-footer {background:url("image.png") ; float:right; margin-right:0;width:172px;height:38px;}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
<div class="text">
  some text here
  
  <div id="logo-footer"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/css-vertical-align-middle-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display:table-cell` and `line-height:38px;` for this.

```
#footer { height: 80px; display:table;background:red;}
#footer .text{display:table-cell;margin: 0 auto; width: 1024px;height:100%; vertical-align:middle;line-height:38px;}
#footer .text #logo-footer {background:url("image.png") ; float:right; margin-right:0;width:172px;height:38px;}
```

I made a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/d3m7yxrg/

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it's positioned good! But I added t #footer {width: 100%;} and how to position .text and .logo-footer horizontal in the middle and its width to be 1024px;