# Can't vertical center h1 inside div

Tags: html, css

I'm having some troubles when trying to vertical center a header inside a div.
CSS is the following:

```html
.container {
  background: #a3f;
  padding-left: 3% !important;
}

.container h4 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f02;
}
```

I have tried some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers) (also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/why-is-vertical-align-middle-not-working-on-my-span-or-div)), but the text continues at the top of the div.

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block;` for the header to see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several (5) methods from me:

#### 1. `grid` (2 ways using grid)

```css
.container {
  background: #a3f;
  height: 100px;
  
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  /* or */ /* place-content: center; */
}

.container h4 {
  background: #f02;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4> The header </h4>
</div>
```

#### 2. `flex`

```css
.container {
  background: #a3f;
  height: 100px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container h4 {
  background: #f02;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4> The header </h4>
</div>
```

#### 3. `translate(-50%, -50%)`

```css
.container {
  background: #a3f;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.container h4 {
  background: #f02;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform    : translate(-50%, -50%);  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4> The header </h4>
</div>
```

#### 4. `table`

```css
.container {
  background: #a3f;
  height: 100px;
  
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}

.container h4 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4> The header </h4>
</div>
```

#### 5. `transform: translateY(-50%);` with `position: relative;`

```css
.container {
  background: #a3f;
  height: 100px;
  
}

.container h4 {
  background: #f02;
  
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4> The header </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't use the 5 method for other reasons, but the 1st works perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: Happy it helped. I just wanted to give you options to choose from. Who knows maybe you'll find others useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using flexbox ?

```css
.container {
  background: #a3f;
  padding-left: 3% !important;
  height: 500px;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.container h4 {
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  text-align: center;
  background: #f02;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h4>Blabla</h4>
</div>
```