# Vertically align image inside a bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to code my first website and I have to build a carousel. The thing is I have a smaller image (400x400) that I'm trying to vertically align it into the carousel and some text to the right. I tried with the `position: relative;` on the carousel and `absolute` on the div with the image +

```css
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

doesn't work. I think because of the carousel caption that is next to it..

Here's what is looking right now without the aligning I mentioned above

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDllP.png

Here's the **HTML**:

```
<!-- Start Carousel -->
    <div id="product-detail carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-img"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <p class="cat-title">Mercury</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left control-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right control-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

<!-- End Carousel -->
```

**CSS** I have for the carousel:

```
/*************************
    CAROUSEL
*************************/

.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background: #faf9f9;
}

.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
}

.control-icon {
    color: #393939;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('../img/jewelery.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.cat-title {
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and see if it helps:

First make you `.item` position relative and give it a height of 100% so it takes up the same height as the container `.carousel-inner`

```
.item{
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
}
```

Then next add you absolute position styles back to your `.carousel-img` element

```
.carousel-img {
    ...
    position: absolute;   
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94tbx06t/) for an example.

Also I noticed that you have static heights on your carousel (550px) and on your carousel-img (400px) so you could just add `margin-top:75px;` to your `.carousel-img`

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jej1mzmu/).

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thank you !

Comment: I got the image right but now I have problems with the caption.. It spans the full with of the container but what I'm trying to do is to put the image on the left and some text to right of it.. Here's how it should look -> http://i.imgur.com/AA5peOi.png Any suggestions ?