# How to make bootstrap carousel image in the verticle center with viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, viewport-units

I have a page http://jatinraikwar.com/w/slider.html

In this want to make an image verticle center.
Using **bootstrap carousel**.

The problem is, wants to show the image as it is, but in the center.

Code:

```
<style>
.image-style {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
}
</style>

<body style="background-color: black;">

    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="images/i0.jpg" class="d-block image-style" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/i1.jpg" class="d-block image-style" alt="...">
            </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/i5.jpg" class="d-block image-style" alt="...">
    </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/i3.jpg" class="d-block image-style" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/i0.jpg" class="d-blockimage-style" alt="...">
            </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/i5.jpg" class="d-block" style="max-width: 100vw; max-height: 100vh; margin: auto;" alt="...">
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use `flexbox` for it. But if you can add code snippet for your current implementation, it will be good.

Comment: show your code as well

Comment: Can you try adding `display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100vh;` to `carousal-inner` class.

Comment: @SandipNirmal It's not working, here is a link http://jatinraikwar.com/w/slider.html

Comment: @לבנימלכה Link to the code is mentioned the question and code added to the question. can you please check

Comment: I asked for code because this is kind of rule in this site(code not link (You can add link but first code because link can remove someday) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox and add `100vh` to your `.carousel` and `.carousel-inner`. This is make images vertically centered. Try adding the below snippet to your page.

```
.carousel,
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link, I think it is useful for your explanation.

[Vertically align image inside a bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509980/vertically-align-image-inside-a-bootstrap-carousel)